# Quiet .hashCode() death of a script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a relatively simple script that sometimes and for some users (but never for the owner so far) produces the following execution transcript (beginning of script removed):

```
[14-02-11 14:34:47:418 CET] Range.setValues([[[prg:some-string, 2014.02.11. 14:34:47]]]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:642 CET] SpreadsheetApp.flush() [0.224 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:642 CET] Browser.msgBox([String ....-ot.]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:647 CET] Browser.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:669 CET] CacheService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:670 CET] CalendarApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:670 CET] Charts.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:672 CET] ContactsApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:672 CET] ContentService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:673 CET] DocsList.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:673 CET] DocumentApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:675 CET] DriveApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:675 CET] FinanceApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:676 CET] FormApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:677 CET] GmailApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:678 CET] GroupsApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:679 CET] GroupsManager.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:679 CET] HtmlService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:680 CET] Jdbc.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:681 CET] LanguageApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:681 CET] LockService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:682 CET] Logger.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:685 CET] MailApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:685 CET] Maps.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:685 CET] NicknameManager.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:685 CET] ScriptApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:687 CET] ScriptDb.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:687 CET] ScriptProperties.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:687 CET] Session.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:688 CET] SitesApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:688 CET] SoapService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:689 CET] SpreadsheetApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:689 CET] UiApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:691 CET] UrlFetchApp.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:691 CET] UserManager.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:691 CET] UserProperties.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:691 CET] Utilities.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:692 CET] Xml.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:692 CET] XmlService.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] Spreadsheet.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] Range.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] Range.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] User.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] User.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:696 CET] Sheet.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:697 CET] Sheet.hashCode() [0 seconds]
[14-02-11 14:34:47:697 CET] Sheet.hashCode() [0 seconds]
```

Note, that the transcript doesn't finish with the customary Execution succeeded/execution failed message. This is the very end of the whole transcript.

What could be triggering this?

Here is the relevant portion of the script:

```
      var paymentRow2 = [ 
        "prg:"+event.user.getEmail(), 
        Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "yyyy.MM.dd. HH:mm:ss")
      ];
      paymentSheet.getRange(paymentRowToWrite, 1, 1, paymentRow.length).setValues([paymentRow]);
      paymentSheet.getRange(paymentRowToWrite, 10, 1, paymentRow2.length).setValues([paymentRow2]);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Browser.msgBox("String" + dateAmount + "-ot.");
      //
      // Dies here -- seems to happen always after Browser.msgBox()
      //
      if (repeatingPayment) {
        if (inputRow[0] != "Hetente") {
          sheet.getRange(modifiedRowNum, 7, 1, 5).setValues([["","","","",""]]);
        }
        undoCommand(event);
      } else 
        if ((dateAmount == totalAmount) || (!GeneralUtil.isNumber(totalAmount))) {
          sheet.deleteRow(modifiedRowNum);
        } else { 
          sheet.getRange(modifiedRowNum, 5, 1, 7).setValues([[Math.round(totalAmount - dateAmount),inputRow[5],"","","","",""]]);
          undoCommand(event);
        }
      break;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: As a workaround, can you place your msgBox as the last call on your script? `msgBox` have a history of issues (which seemed to be solved).

Comment: Too bad one has to resort to such workarounds. It did the trick however. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does this describe your issue?

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2697

tl:dr scripts using an onEdit trigger fail silently following call for Browser.msgBox for everyone but the owner.

Comment: Yes, it does. There is more than one msgBox call, and the previous ones are successfully passed even for other users, and here it stops, but not always.  Based on the issue report you mentioned, it seems that this has not been resolved yet. Thanks for the reference.