# When executed by someone else, the script execution does not resume after a call to Browser.msgBox()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet where we mention some kind task our team has to do. Under one column we maintain the task status. I have added a Google app script which is triggered on change of spreadsheet. The main job of script is to send email notifications to some Google mailing groups about the change.
In the script I have used Browser.msgBox() to get input in yes/no. Now if I change the status in spreadsheet the popup comes and script resumes on button click with the value of button. If someone else make a change in spreadsheet, he gets the popup but on clicking the yes/no button  script does not resumes.

My script looks something like this:

```
function statusChangeNotification(e) {
  var user = e.user;
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var val = e.value;

  if(sheet.getName() == RESPONSE_SHEET && isStatusField(range)){
    if(val == STATUS_YES){
      var sendMail = Browser.msgBox("Status Changed", "Do you wanna send a status notification mail?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
      if(sendMail == "yes"){
        // code to send email using MailApp.sendEmail()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On Google developer under [class browser reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser) they have mentioned that

> msgBox(title, prompt, buttons)
>
> Pops up a dialog box with the given title, message and specified
>   buttons in the user's browser. The msgBox method raises a client-side
>   message box with the given title, that displays the given message to
>   the user, and offers a choice of buttons to be displayed. Note that
>   this method causes the server-side script to be suspended. It will
>   resume automatically after the user clears the dialog, but JDBC
>   connections will not persist across the suspension.

What could be the problem that the script does not resume after a call to Browser.msgBox() for others? Please suggest some alternatives to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following thread:

[Quiet .hashCode() death of a script (GAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742883/quiet-hashcode-death-of-a-script-gas/21755650#21755650)

Also, this logged GAS issue:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2697

tl/dr script will fail after Browser.msgBox() for all users other than script+spreadsheet owner

Comment: Hi @samscholefield,
You are right. There is case logged on Google forum but is there any workaround to overcome this?

Comment: Hello @Nitesh. The workaround is to use UiApp to create a custom 'dialog' box and return any values input back to the script.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, you are using an `onEdit` trigger to send an Email after a popup confirmation. onEdit trigger is a simple trigger and it has limited scope.
You can not send email with onEdit event. You will have to use Installable Triggers like time driven triggers etc.

For better understanding of triggers and its scope, you may check these two reference links.

- [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)
- [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers)

Comment: Hi @waqar-ahmad, you are right. I am using onEdit trigger. But I am saying that there is no issue in sending the mails. Everything works when fine when I edit the spreadsheet. But when someone else edit the spreadsheet, script is triggered, confirmation pop up appears and after that script is terminated. If I remove the msgBox() pop up then script continues execution and mail is sent for others edit too.