# SpreadsheetApp Class and triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an [SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) 'onEdit' attached to a new spreadsheet created programmatically. This new spreadsheet is shared in EDIT mode to other users not necessarily within the same domain.

Basically the trigger edits a cell when the user inputs a certain value. If the value is incorrect, first I show a prompt message then I erase the value. If I use the following:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(prompt);`

I see the prompt message but the cell content isn't cleared. But when I use the following it works:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(msg);`

I don't understand why it has this behavior ? Could anyone explain me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the same issue as reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2697): a  browser alert terminates the execution of a triggered script under some circumstances. Using a "toast" is a decent workaround. See also [When executed by someone else, the script execution does not resume after a call to Browser.msgBox()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23796641)